# Replacing pixel with % in css design to position element

Tags: html, css

I am not proficient with css. But Iget my work done after googling.

For positioning the element in specific location I use:

```
<div style="position:fixed; left:30px; top:200px;">
```

If Rather then using `pixels` If I want to use % then what is the funda or calculation criteria for that?

Comment: It should be the width of the document in this case

Comment: @Pekka웃: Thanks but I want answer for generalized situation. Not for this particular example

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is not accurate if you calculate it on any basis, because it should be the width of the document in this case.

Just for reference and simple idea please check it out http://www.getallfix.com/2011/11/convert-empxpt-and-in-css/. May be it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Its simple, just use basic math (Rule of 3):

> Width in Pixels x 100 / Total Element Width
>
> Height in Pixels x 100 / Total Element Height

Ex:
Lets suppose, that your element has the area of 1000px (height x width)

> 30px x 100 / 1000px = 3%
>
> 200px x 100 / 1000px = 20%

**Little Observation:**
*If the Height of the element is not defined, try to use pixels instead.*